# Why is the function printing a variable that I have not yet assigned locally

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm still in the process of learning python and there is a problem that I am not able to understand.

```
def demo():
  print(a)
  a += 5

a = 100
print(a)
demo()
print(a)
```

If i run this program it gives a traceback error which is obvious. But the problem comes when I run the below code.

```
def demo():
  print(a)

a = 100
print(a)
demo()
print(a)
```

If I remove the `a += 5` line then the program runs just fine and produce the output -

```
100
100
100
```

My question is that it should still give traceback error because I still have not yet defined what `a` is in the function body and neither did I give `a` as argument. But it doesn't give the error. Can anyone  please explain it to me why it is ?

Comment: In the second one a is a global variable, in the first one since you try to change it in the function it is a local one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UnboundLocalError trying to use a variable (supposed to be global) that is (re)assigned (even after first use)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/370357/unboundlocalerror-trying-to-use-a-variable-supposed-to-be-global-that-is-rea)

Comment: And [Why isn't the 'global' keyword needed to access a global variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4693120/6045800)

Answer (score 1):

In this case, a is in the global/module scope. It can be read from functions as long as it's only read, but if a function writes to it then it's assumed to be local so it will cause the print to error. If you do want to assign to the global `a` from `demo` you have to mark it as such with a `global` statement.

```py
def demo():
  global a
  print(a)
  a += 5

a = 100
print(a)
demo()
print(a)
```

```
100
100
105
```